# Import not working with JavaScript in PhpStorm/Webstorm

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, phpstorm, webstorm

I'm trying to run a piece of JavaScript code written in a tutorial that looks like this:

**main.js**

```
import Vue from 'Vue';
import Alert from './components/Alert.vue';

new Vue({
    el: 'body',

    components: { Alert }
})
```

However, PhpStorm is giving the following error:

> Import declarations are not supported by current JavaScript version

How I can get a newer(?) JavaScript version in PhpStorm? Is that really the problem here?

Answer (score 168, accepted):

In your preferences, change the version of javascript to ECMAScript 6.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  PhpStorm is no longer showing an error; however, the Chrome console is displaying this:  Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import - main.js:1   Do you know what is going on here?

Comment: Actually I believe it is an unrelated error.  Thanks again!

Comment: Now it is asking me whether I want to use Babel to convert from 6 to 5.1.

Comment: ok... So tell it what you want to do @nueverest yes or no ;-)

Comment: Does this mean I'm going to have two copies of the same file in my js folder i.e. one for 6 and one for 5.1?  I found typescript annoying because I would have three files / typescript file.  A project with 100 typescripts files would have 300 files that a person would need to filter through.

Comment: if you use typescript the extension of your file should be .ts.

Comment: @nueverest the built files should never be committed to your version control, only the src files

Comment: I got this error in Pycharm and changing the JavaScript version to 'Flow' stopped the import statements from being highlighted as errors. Changing it to 'ECMAScript 6' did not.

Comment: for people needing a step by step

File > Settings > Languages & frameworks and the rest is same

Comment: That works to avoid the asked error, but now, I am getting an unexpected expression in Chrome. Where can I use this Javascripts syntax?

Comment: for rubymine file>settings>Language & Framework>javascript> ECMAScript 6