# Laravel VueJS keep getting errors with vueJS

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-5, phpstorm

I keep getting errors when I try to do simple things. It works perfectly but it just says `Method definition shorthands are not supported by current JavaScript version`. I just don't get it, I never had this problem before.

[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The syntax,

```
methods: {
   addMessage(message){
     this.messages.push(message)
   }
}
```

Is the newer Ecmascript method shorthand syntax. It sounds like your editor doesn't like it for some reason. You can use the old school syntax.

```
methods: {
   addMessage: function (message){
     this.messages.push(message)
   }
}
```

It looks like you can [set the javascript version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36295525/import-not-working-with-javascript-in-phpstorm) as a setting.

Comment: I guess you beat me to it (by 55 secs!).

Comment: @d00dle Thats how it goes sometimes :)