# Why does WebStorm add an import-statement to the top of my js-file?

Tags: javascript, webstorm

Sometimes when working with WebStorm editing a .js file I see an import statement gets automatically inserted to the top of the file, like following:

```
import {setTimeout} from "../../typings/globals/node";
```

It then causes an error because "import" is not understood.

I'd like to understand why this happens so I can prevent it from happening.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/36295554/794088

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can disable auto-import completely in **Settings | Editor | General | Auto Import**; also, if you don't like to see warnings regarding non-imported modules, try disabling **JavaScript | General | Missing import statement** inspection (**Settings | Editor | Inspections**)